# Swift SKEmitterNode width

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Good day, I am trying to use a SKEmitterNode in swift, but I can't seem to be able to change its' width, so the particles only cover half of the screen.

My code:

```
if let particles = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Snow.sks") {
        particles.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width/2, frame.size.height)
        particles.targetNode = self.scene
        particles.zPosition = 999
        addChild(particles)
    }
```

How can I make the particles to cover the whole screen width?

Comment: You can play with the settings in the Particle Editor to get the effect however you like it

Comment: @Knight0fDragon this is probably correct, but doesn't answer my question though. I am unable to get the right setting to have an emitter of a full screen size.

Comment: well nobody can answer this question, because nobody can know what you truly want, and there are tons of settings to achieve desired effect,  all you will get are guesses and suggestions.  Just play with the settings till you get a desired result,  there is not a lot to choose from,  will take you 15 minutes

Comment: @Knight0fDragon of course someone knows the answer, because someone has achieved the full screen width before.

Comment: no, there is no specific answer, what 1 person suggests may or may not work with you because the other settings on your emitter can change the results, that is called guessing, not answering. Seriously stop wasting time debating and just play with the emitter.  You will learn more about what the other settings do and get a sense of accomplishment for doing something on your own,  this is not a question for SO.

Comment: I think that before asking in Stackoverflow is a good practice read the documentation before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at the so called "emitter editor", as suggested by @Knight0fDragon, I was able to find the right parameter - `particlePositionRange`

```
if let particles = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Snow.sks") {
        particles.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width/2, frame.size.height)
        particles.targetNode = self.scene

        // frame.size.width to cover the length of the screen.
        particles.particlePositionRange = CGVector(dx: frame.size.width, dy: frame.size.height) 
        particles.zPosition = 999
        addChild(particles)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Through the position and **particlePositionRange** you can get your goal

By the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skemitternode):

> particlePositionRange

### Declaration

```
var particlePositionRange: CGVector { get set }
```

### Discussion

The default value is (0.0,0.0). If a component is non-zero, the same component of a particle’s position is randomly determined and may vary by plus or minus half of the range value